# Two dimensional rank using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the data I'm dealing with:

[image]

I would like to find a way, in sql, of adding numbers to the yellow column which will rank the Names in such a way that I get the following.

note: This is the final pivoted result - in the `sql` table there is no need to pivot the data.

[image]

This ranking is decided via these rules:

1. The most recent week (ie Wk5 column) is the most important.
2. The next most recent week is next most important.
3. ...so on to the left with the oldest week column "WK1" being the least important.
4. A data value that is small e.g. 1, is best. A data value that is high e.g. 7, is not good. A blank space is the worst and if at all possible should be located near the bottom of the page - but rules 1/2/3 always take precedence.

This is the data with a placeholder of 0 in the column `Idx`:

```
CREATE TABLE #values 
    (
        Name    varchar(5), 
        Idx     int,
        "Week"  varchar(5), 
        Amount  int
    );

INSERT INTO #values
VALUES
    ('A',0,'WK1',3),
    ('T',0,'WK1',2),
    ('H',0,'WK1',1),
    ('P',0,'WK1',4),
    ('V',0,'WK1',6),
    ('N',0,'WK1',5),
    ('A',0,'WK2',2),
    ('F',0,'WK2',1),
    ('K',0,'WK2',3),
    ('P',0,'WK2',4),
    ('W',0,'WK2',7),
    ('V',0,'WK2',5),
    ('B',0,'WK2',6),
    ('A',0,'WK3',1),
    ('F',0,'WK3',2),
    ('T',0,'WK3',3),
    ('K',0,'WK3',4),
    ('W',0,'WK3',5),
    ('V',0,'WK3',6),
    ('N',0,'WK3',7),
    ('A',0,'WK4',2),
    ('F',0,'WK4',1),
    ('T',0,'WK4',5),
    ('K',0,'WK4',4),
    ('B',0,'WK4',6),
    ('A',0,'WK5',1),
    ('F',0,'WK5',2),
    ('T',0,'WK5',3),
    ('H',0,'WK5',4),
    ('K',0,'WK5',5);
```

This is my current attempt:

```
WITH  
allData AS
    (
        SELECT  Name,
                "Week",
                newRank = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY "Week" DESC,Amount)
        FROM    #values
    )
,allData2 AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                newRank2 = 1 / CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,10),newRank)
        FROM    allData
    )
,allData3 AS
    (
        SELECT  Name,
                smRank  = SUM(newRank2)
        FROM    allData2
        GROUP BY Name
    )
SELECT  Name,
        smRank,
        rnk = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY smRank DESC)
INTO    #RankA
FROM    allData3;



UPDATE      X
SET         X.Idx = Y.rnk
FROM        #values X
            INNER JOIN #RankA   Y ON
                X.Name = Y.Name;
```

Unfortunately if I pivot the results, and then order by the `Idx` column it is not in the order I am aiming at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on two nested `ROW_NUMBER`s:

```
select *,
   row_number() 
   over (order by "Week" desc, amount)
from
 (
   select *,
      row_number()
      over (partition by name 
            order by "Week" desc, amount) as rn
   from #values
 ) as dt
where rn = 1 -- for each name find the latest week and it's lowest number
```

What if two names share the same week/amount? You might consider `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Using your #values table, here is how to pivot it (since the data you provided was not in the same table format) and then assign a value to the index based on your requirements.

```
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN wk5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk5, CASE WHEN wk4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk4, CASE WHEN wk3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,wk3, CASE WHEN wk2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,wk2, CASE WHEN wk1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk1) AS new_index

from (
select * from #values
) p
PIVOT (
MAX(Amount) 
FOR [week] IN (wk1, wk2, wk3, wk4, wk5)) AS pvt
```

USING DYNAMIC FOR 52 WEEKS

```
DECLARE @COLS AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@QUERY  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT @COLS = STUFF(( SELECT distinct ','+QUOTENAME(C.[week])
FROM #values AS C
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

SET @QUERY = '
select *
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN wk5 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk5, CASE WHEN wk4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk4, CASE WHEN wk3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,wk3, CASE WHEN wk2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,wk2, CASE WHEN wk1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, wk1) AS new_index

from (
select * from #values
) p
PIVOT (
MAX(Amount) 
FOR [week] IN (' + @cols+ ')) AS pvt'

EXEC(@QUERY)
```

Comment: I like this. I just want your two columns `new_index` and `Name`  but it looks like you use the pivot to force the order - without having to come up with some crazy algorithm to base the rank on. Only problem now is that the production table contains 52 weeks!

Comment: very quick response, appreciated: